# Node.js is blocking?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, blocking

**I think I just discovered something really weird with either node.js or the browsers. So node.js should be non-blocking but a simple setTimeout blocks the whole website for the same client.**

### This is the server code:

```
// Create HTTP Server
var http = require('http');

// Create page number holder
var page = 0;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    // Increment Page Number
    page++; 

    // Log page load
    console.log('LOAD PAGE', page); 

    // Set response header
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); 

    // Wait 10 seconds and write Hello World message to client.
    setTimeout(function(){ res.end('Hello World\n'); }, 10000); 

}).listen(5000); // Listen on port 5000

// Log server start
console.log('Server running on port 5000.');
```

So what I'm talking about is when I try to open http://mysite.com:5000/ in Chrome(Version 25.0.1364.152) with two tabs, the first tab has to finish before the second tab is being processed by node.js.

### It looks like this:

```
Client: Open Tab1 
> server console: LOAD PAGE 1

Client: Open Tab2
> server console: Nothing happens

Server: Wait 10 seconds
> server console: LOAD PAGE 2
```

I would expect node.js to run both requests right away otherwise this is not non-blocking. I already tested this with Firefox 19, so it seems browsers behave the same way regarding this.

So what's happening? Am I missing something?? :OOOO

### UPDATE

I just run the tests in Safari(6.0.2) and it works normally, so this might be a browser issue with Chrome and Firefox and maybe others.

*Tested with Node.js Version **v0.6.17** and **v0.8.21***

Comment: I would hazard a guess, that not so much the whole server hangs, but your browser wants to reuse a keepalive connection... What happens if you (a) try the second request from a different IP (b) try the request from a different browser and (c) If you give `{'Content-Type': 'text/plain','Connection':'close'}` as headers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A browser implements the concurrent connection limit per domain name. Snip:

> Browsers typically limit the number of concurrent HTTP connections per
>   server to be 2(the term “per server" is used broadly here for the sake
>   of simplicity. For example, it could be multiple physical machines
>   sharing the same public IP.). If a browser session has two HTTP
>   connections already, any further connection requests will have to wait
>   until one of these two HTTP connections is finished. As a result, the
>   browser (or the application) appears to be locked up. Though the "two
>   connection limit" made sense years ago, it is very problematic in
>   today's Ajax enabled "web 2.0" applications.

Source: http://www.openajax.org/runtime/wiki/The_Two_HTTP_Connection_Limit_Issue

Node is not blocking, your browser is. I recommend apache benchmark (ab -c 10 -n 10) for tests.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're missing something
You should try testing your server with something else than a full-blown web browser. try `curl` for example.

Chrome does a lot of other things than doing what you told it to do.

Comment: I just tried this with Safari and it works there, so it's probably a browser related issue. But since Chrome and Firefox are the most popular browsers it's really weird :\

Comment: believe me. Node.js is not blocking.
Chrome only allows two concurrent requests to the same host. I'm assuming here that, since it's downloading the page and /favicon.ico it's just waiting for one of them to finish before starting with the second tab

Comment: I believe you, it makes sense.